# Uninstall Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: uninstall, mac

I need to uninstall Ubuntu 16.04 because of problems I’m having.

Ubuntu 16.04 is installed alone on an Apple iMac Internal 1TB disk.
I’m having the following major problems with Ubuntu:

- Firefox goes into Script Mode when downloading files.
- LibreOffice Calc, entering data into cells sometimes blacks out part of the data entered.
- The Calculator.app keeps self-loading, it is very annoying. Today it has self-loaded 5 copies whilst using LibreOffice Writer.

Will someone please assist me?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling an operating system does not make sense. What should remain after you uninstall OS? An unbootable partition? Simple formatting will do it, too.

Just install the desired OS and set it to be installed to the same disk partition.

Comment: How to Install a different Distro?

Comment: Download and install it like you did with Ubuntu…